# Stop script from happening when I resize down the window and do another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, responsive-design, navbar

I'm trying to make a responsive navbar on a website. I have a script running to add some effects to navbar.But when window size is less than 700 px I want to stop everything that I'm doing with the navbar, and do another script.I'm doing this for mobile devices but also I want this to happen when the user resizes down the window.

My problem is : It's ok when the width is > 700px ,but when i resize down to less than 700px the script is still running, and i don't want that.

Also it works ok if the page first loads with the width less than 700px,but that doesn't solves the problem.

I have my script here with a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zq73qp70/4/):

```
var WindowWidth = $(window).width();

$(document).ready(function($) {
  handleNav();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    //here i call the function again after i resize to check if the condition of window width > 700px is stil true

    WindowWidth = $(window).width();
    handleNav();
  });
});


function handleNav() {

  if (WindowWidth > 700) {
    $(document).scroll(function() {

      if (300 / $(document).scrollTop() > 0.5 && $(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#abs-header').css({
          'opacity': (500 / ($(document).scrollTop() + 1))
        });
        $('#abs-header').css({
          'background-color': 'rgba(113, 20, 20,1)'
        });
      }

      if ($(document).scrollTop() < 100) {
        $('#abs-header').css({
          'background-color': 'transparent'
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    //Other code here that i didn't make yet but I want to hapen when the window is less than 700px wide.
  }
}
```

I tried multiple aproaches, neither of those worked.I really need your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you add the `scroll` event handler when the screen is more than 700px and then it just keeps running regardless of the later widths.

Correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    handleNav();

    $(window).resize(function(){

        //here i call the function again after i resize to check if the condition of window width > 700px is stil true            
        handleNav();    
   });
});


function handleNav() {

    if ( $(window).width() > 700) {
        $(document).scroll(function() {

            if(300 / $(document).scrollTop() > 0.5 && $(document).scrollTop() > 100){
                $('#abs-header').css({'opacity': (500 / ($(document).scrollTop()+1))});
                $('#abs-header').css({'background-color' : 'rgba(113, 20, 20,1)'});
            }

            if($(document).scrollTop() < 100){
                $('#abs-header').css({'background-color' : 'transparent'});
            }
        });
    } else {
        //Other code here that i didn't make yet but I want to hapen when the window is less than 700px wide.

        // remove handler
        $(document).off('scroll');

    }
}
```

or rather just put your logic inside scroll handler and check the width there

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if ( $(window).width() > 700) {
            if (300 / $(document).scrollTop() > 0.5 && $(document).scrollTop() > 100){
                $('#abs-header').css({'opacity': (500 / ($(document).scrollTop()+1))});
                $('#abs-header').css({'background-color' : 'rgba(113, 20, 20,1)'});
            }

            if($(document).scrollTop() < 100){
                $('#abs-header').css({'background-color' : 'transparent'});
            }
        } else {
             //Other code here that i didn't make yet but I want to hapen when the window is less than 700px wide.
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most obvious solution would be to put the if statement INSIDE the scroll function.

I might be wrong, but it may turn out that the document stores the function which it must execute. And when your IF-ELSE is false, the function is there already.

So I suggest something like

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if (WindowWidth > 700) {
    ....
```

The other way would be to assign a different function to the same event in the ELSE clause.

Answer (score 1):

When your page loads with width>700 px, the function is attached to the scroll event. So when the width is getting less you must remove it explicitly. On the other hand, when the window is loaded with width<700, the function is not attached with the scroll event - so it works fine. Once the width gets high it gets attached and start working accordingly.

So either detach the function from scroll, or check the width inside the function as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

once you assign `$(document).scroll` the first time,
it's always going to execute, regardless of size

so, assign the same handler instead

```
var WindowWidth = $(window).width();

$(document).ready(function($) {
  handleNav();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    WindowWidth = $(window).width();
    handleNav();
  });
  $(document).scroll(handleNav);
});

function handleNav() {
  if (WindowWidth > 700) {
    if (300 / $(document).scrollTop() > 0.5 && $(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('#abs-header').css({
        'opacity': (500 / ($(document).scrollTop() + 1))
      });
      $('#abs-header').css({
        'background-color': 'rgba(113, 20, 20,1)'
      });
    }

    if ($(document).scrollTop() < 100) {
      $('#abs-header').css({
        'background-color': 'transparent'
      });
    }
  } else {
    //Other code here that i didn't make yet but I want to hapen when the window is less than 700px wide.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i changed a bit the JQ structure. it works now ( on resize ! not on refresh ! )

check snippet below or jsfiddle > [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zq73qp70/4/)

in my example if you are above `700px`, the bck of the `#abs-header` is `red`, and if you are under `700px`, the bck of the `#abs-header` is `blue`

let me know if this works for you

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).on("resize",function(){
      
  





    if ($(window).width() > 700){
        $(document).scroll(function(){

            if(300 / $(document).scrollTop() > 0.5 && $(document).scrollTop() > 100){
                $('#abs-header').css({'opacity': (500 / ($(document).scrollTop()+1))});
                $('#abs-header').css({'background-color' : 'rgba(113, 20, 20,1)'});
            }

            if($(document).scrollTop() < 100){
                $('#abs-header').css({'background-color' : 'transparent'});
            }
        });
    }else{
       $(document).scroll(function(){
         if(300 / $(document).scrollTop() > 0.5 && $(document).scrollTop() > 100){
           $('#abs-header').css({'background-color' : 'blue'});
        }
        if($(document).scrollTop() < 100){
       $('#abs-header').css({'background-color' : 'transparent'});
       }
       });
    }
});
});
```

```css
#abs-header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear,background-color 0.2s linear;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    z-index: 1001;
    font-size: 13px;
    
}
#abs-header a{
    color: white;
}

#main-menu-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-flex;
}
nav#main-nav{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
nav#main-nav > .nav > li{
    margin: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 65px;
}
nav#main-nav > .nav > li:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #e1e1e1;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.05s linear;
}
nav#main-nav .sub-menu li:hover a{
    color:#711414;
}
/*Hovering the deep one*/
nav#main-nav > .nav > .deeper:hover:before{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
/*Adjusting position to deep ones(because of the arrow)*/
nav#main-nav > .nav > .deeper:before{
    left:-10px;
}
/*The active one*/
nav#main-nav > .nav > .active:before{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
/*When hovering*/
nav#main-nav > .nav > li:hover:before{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
p{
font-size:8px;
}
img{
  height 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="abs-header">
            <div id="main-menu-container">
                <nav id="main-nav">
                    <ul class="nav">
                      <li class="item-119 default"><a href="/vatra/index.php/en/">Home</a></li>
                      <li class="item-150"><a href="/vatra/index.php/en/about-us">About us</a></li>
                      <li class="item-151 current active"><a href="/vatra/index.php/en/contact-us">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </nav>
    
</div>
</header>

<img src="http://dragonflycap.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/brick-1.jpg" />
<p>
CONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERCONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONCONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONCONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONCONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONCONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONCONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONCONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONCONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONCONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONE
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for quick and fast replies!I understand now the problem with the scroll event.I chose to do it this way :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    handleNav();
});

function handleNav() {
    jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
        if(jQuery(window).width() > 993){
            if(300 / jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 0.5 && jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 100){
                jQuery('#abs-header').css({'opacity': (500 / (jQuery(document).scrollTop()+1))});
                jQuery('.home-page #abs-header').css({'background-color' : 'rgba(113, 20, 20,1)'});
            }

            if(jQuery(document).scrollTop() < 100){
                jQuery('.home-page #abs-header').css({'background-color' : 'transparent'});
            }

        }
        else
            {
                //other code here
            }
    });
}
```

I don't know wich answer to chose because you all answered my question.I'll chose the one that helped me understand the most.